# Prevent mix deps.get using the network if the deps are up to date?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'm attempting to make an escrow build of some Elixir code. That is: I want to provide a tarball that contains everything needed to build my project.

So: I run `mix deps.get` while building the tarball, which works fine.

To verify that the build has everything, I'm running it on a machine (actually a docker container) that has no connection to the Internet.

But when I run `make`, which runs `mix deps.get`, it attempts to hit `repo.hex.pm`, even though the dependencies are up to date (according to `mix.lock`).

How do I stop it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do it.

You probably should not run the `mix deps.get` on that container, it will fails on the compile task if you don't have all the dependencies.